# NSDate: Getting values for Tomorrow or Yesterday

Tags: swift, nsdate, uidatepicker, nscalendar

I have a piece of code that basically acts in 2 parts:

Part 1: The user sets a Date with a `UIDatePicker`. For example, the user selects 1 day ahead from the current date. So the selected new date is 5/19/16 instead of 5/18/16.

**Part 1 code**

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
var  dateString = "May-19-2016"
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM-dd-yyyy"

var due_date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)!
```

Part 2: I have created code that counts how many days are left from the selected date to the current date. In this example, somehow my code is saying its 0 days before tomorrow. Here is the code for the second part:

**Second Part:**

```
func computeDates(dueDate:NSDate)-> Int {

let currentDate = NSDate()

// Adding days to currentDate
let daysToAdd = 1

// Adding on Unit to the current instance
let calculateDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.Day, value: daysToAdd, toDate: currentDate, options: NSCalendarOptions.init(rawValue: 0))

// Figure out many days from may 3rd
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

let unit = NSCalendarUnit.Day

let components = cal.components(unit, fromDate: currentDate, toDate: dueDate, options: [])

let countLeft = components.day

return countLeft
}

print("Days left: \(computeDates(due_date)) ")


// Tests
let calc_date = computeDates(due_date)

if calc_date <= -1 {
    print("Yesterday")
} else if calc_date == 0 {
    print("Today")
} else if calc_date > 1 {          
    print("Tomorrow")
}
```

In the part 1 example, I used a static date which I use to test this code. In this part, I set May 19, 2016, one day ahead. In the second part below in the if statement, It somehow says I have 0 days left and from what i am trying to do, it's suppose to say 1 day left before tomorrow the 19th.

Another example, If i change the 19th to the 20th, I want it to say **"In 2 days"** from now.

Now if I revert the day to lets say, the 15th of may (in the past), Then the if statement would say something like Overdue or the past.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Be careful with expressions like "in 2 days", because they are very hard to localize. In some languages it is not clear to which date it will refer.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you thought of `NSDate` as a structure that operates with the number of seconds from 2001. It means if you pick a *"date"*, it contains *"date and time"*. All you need to do to calculate the correct number of days between specific *"dates"* is to truncate a time component.

But if you only need to check whether the provided date is Yesterday, Today, or Tomorrow, `NSCalendar` has methods for this purpose:

Objective-C:

```
- (BOOL)isDateInToday:(NSDate *)date NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 8_0);
- (BOOL)isDateInYesterday:(NSDate *)date NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 8_0);
- (BOOL)isDateInTomorrow:(NSDate *)date NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 8_0);
```

And Swift:

```
@available(OSX 10.9, *)
public func isDateInYesterday(date: NSDate) -> Bool

@available(OSX 10.9, *)
public func isDateInTomorrow(date: NSDate) -> Bool

@available(OSX 10.9, *)
public func isDateInWeekend(date: NSDate) -> Bool
```

Comment: Are these methods available in Swift 2?